# Move a site collection to Office 365

Tags: restore, sharepoint-online

I have a web application with one site collection in an on-premise SharePoint 2010 test environment that I would like to migrate to Office 365. Is there a way to backup and restore or do I need to recreate everything manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this using [Metalogix migration manager](http://www.metalogix.com/products/migration-manager-for-sharepoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx) for this with success.

Comment: Hm, looks like an interesting tool. Have you ever had problems using it, if so what kinda problems have there been?